# Getting Null returned from taxonomy field in PowerShell?

Tags: taxonomy, term-store, term, powershell

I am trying to update a metadata field when adding an item to document library. All the other columns are updating. The error is on this line and basically $taxfield is returning null.

```
$taxField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$spItem.Fields["Region"]
$termSet = $termStore.GetTermSet($taxField.TermSetId) >> error on this line.
```

I am running this code with Admin and have full permission to the list.

= = = Error = = =

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\ps\AddFile.ps1:60 char:30
>   +     $taxFieldState.SetFieldValue <<<< ($spItem, $termsST)
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SetFieldValue:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: try using the $list.Fields["Region"] instead of $spItem

Comment: Did not help. $list=$web.Lists["Monthly Sales Report"]

Comment: What do you get when you use `$taxField = $spItem.Fields["Region"]`. Also try and paste some more of your code so we can understand what you are doing

Comment: Do you use a localized version of SharePoint? The DisplayName of the field may be language-dependant! Can you get the field by its InternalName property (like $spItem.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("InternalNameOfYourField")?